# Is a 15" laptop with full HD useable on a daily basis?

Tags: laptop, resolution, high-definition

Or would I have to probably work on a lower resolution? I have a 17" and it is too big to transport around. Not sure if this is the right place to ask but google search listed it as the first place for questions about laptops.

Comment: "useable" - this is a very relative term both in interpretation and also different from person to person. What programs do you run on it? How much time do you spend in front of it? Is it comfortable for your eyes? I think these you need to decide for yourself. Unfortunately your question doesn't fit to this site and likely will be closed as primary opinion based.

Comment: Purely depends on your requirements. 15" tends to be still fairly heavy (2-3kg). What kind of work you do will determine what kind of laptop specs you will need. And yes this will be very opinion-based. So in a way "usable" yes. Does it fit your need - that is up to you.

Comment: I use mainly inkscape, gimp, virtualbox, illustrator and aptana studio. The laptop will be running ubuntu in case it matters

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from personal experience, I wouldn't want anything less than full HD on my 15" laptop.

It is smaller and needs some getting used to the first few days, but Windows is resized to 125%, so that it feels more like what you're used to. So yes, I really recommend it.

Personally I've even changed this to 100%, but I'm still quite young. This preference might be different depending on your age, your eyes and personal choices.